# Prompt dialog issue with clicking ok or cancel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written the below code to submit form and ask for Ok / Cancel. On clicking Ok i have to execute one method on clicking Cancel i want to stay on the same page without reloading but strangely even after clicking cancel also its executing. Can anybody help me on this?

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary1" class="nav-btn"
                                        [disabled]="firstFormGroup.invalid" (click)="manualEP();">Save & Reload Spec
</button>
```

**Logic:**

```
    manualEP() {
            if (this.project.manualEpFound == true) {
              window.confirm("Reloading spec will be deleted manually added endpoint. Do you wish to continue?")
this.refreshSpecs();
            } 
          }
    
    refreshSpecs() {
        this.getTextIn();
        var owner = [];
        for (let u1 of this.project.entitledUsers) {
          if (u1.entitlementType == "OWNER") {
            owner.push(u1);
          }
        }
        this.project.entitledUsers = [];
        for (let u2 of owner) {
          this.project.entitledUsers.push(u2);
        }
        for (let u1 of this.allowedUsers) {
          this.project.entitledUsers.push(u1);
        }
        this.handler.activateLoader();
        this.snackbarService.openSnackBar(
          "Saving  project " + this.project.name + "...",
          ""
        );
    
        if (this.project.openText != null || (this.project.openAPISpec != "" && this.project.openAPISpec != 'None'))
          this.project.noApi = false;
        
        this.projectService.refreshSpecs(this.project).subscribe(
          results => {
            this.handler.hideLoader();
            if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
              return;
            }
            this.snackbarService.openSnackBar(
              "Project " + this.project.name + " saved and API Spec Reload is in progress. It will take few seconds to complete.",
              ""
            );
            this.router.navigate(["/app/projects/" + this.project.id + "/dashboard"]);
          },
          error => {
            this.handler.hideLoader();
            this.handler.error(error);
          }
        );
      }
```

Comment: inside the tag of your cancel button did you try to add type="button"?

Comment: For window.confrim, by default we will get Ok and Cancel. So how can i write inside cancel button?

Comment: `ìf (window.confirm(....){..you click ok..}else{..you click cancel..}`, see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: I tried something like this which is working when only the condition is true if the condition is false then the click button is not working. manualEP() {
    if (this.project.manualEpFound == true) {
      if(window.confirm("Reloading spec will be deleted manually added endpoint. Do you wish to continue?")) {
      this.refreshSpecs(); 
      }
    }
  }

Comment: @youeye sorry, i thought there was a cancel button as well, when you don't add the type on a button in a form it may submit the form like a submit button